# RSA подпись в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

В обычном ASP.NET для RSA подписи/проверки я использовал класс `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider`.
С ним все понятно.

Вот только в ASP.NET Core, как я понял, его нет. Есть только абстрактный класс `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA` :(

Не подскажите, каким классом надо пользоваться в ASP.NET Core для алгоритмов RSA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо добавить в `project.json` nuget-пакет `System.Security.Cryptography.Csp`:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "System.Security.Cryptography.Csp": "4.0.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
}
```

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` из CoreFX немного отличается от аналогичного класса из "взрослого" .NET Framework. Документация по нему есть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider).

Comment: А он крос-платформенный? (я ни как не могу понять как отличать крос-платформенные сборки от тех что работают только под виндами :( )

Comment: @ДмитрийГарбуз да, у таких пактов в описании на nuget.org указаны архитектуры .NETCore и .NETStandard